# How to pass group context to custom form page using group module

Tags: 9, group

I have a custom block that is displayed within each group on every page. The block visibility is set to `/league/*`

The custom block shows up fine for `/league/{gid}`, `/league/{gid}/members`, `/league/{gid}/edit`, `/league/{gid}/invitations` etc.

I created a custom form with a route of `/league/{gid}/segments`, but my block is not rendering correctly on that page because of this line in my block:

`if (($group = $this->getContextValue('group')) && $group->id()) {`

I got that line from the group module `/src/Plugin/Block/GroupOperationsBlock.php`

`$this->getContextValue('group'))` is not defined.

How can I pass the group context to that form page? I tried adding the options of group to the route like this, but no luck:

```
mymodule.segments:
  path: '/league/{gid}/segments'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Segments'
    _form: 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\SegmentsForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'authenticated'
  options:
    parameters:
      group:
        type: 'entity:group'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect it's because you are using `{gid}` and not `{group}`.

Comment: @Jaypan that was indeed the problem. I will accept your answer if you post one

Comment: Done, thanks. And glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the Group to be part of the page context, it needs to be named `{group}` in your path. So you will need to change this:

```
path: '/league/{gid}/segments'
```

To this:

```
path: '/league/{group}/segments'
```